This phone isn't compatible with this app
That is the message I see in Google Play. Different from the rest of my apps, that I have installed on same device using also similar build.gradles.
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
id "com.android.application"
id "kotlin-android"
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('../../apps-keys/timetap/key.properties')
println("Keystore properties file exists: ${keystorePropertiesFile.exists()}")
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    println("Keystore properties loaded: ${keystoreProperties}")
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Keystore properties file not found: $keystorePropertiesFile")
}

android {
    namespace "com.drodriguez.time_tap"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    ndkVersion = '25.1.8937393'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.drodriguez.time_tap"
//        minSdkVersion 23
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:+"
}

If I try to compile like that, it says:

Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller
than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth]
C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\repos\timetap\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\processDebugManifest\AndroidManifest.xml
as the library might be using APIs not available in 21    Suggestion:
use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 21,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

So if I leave minSdkVersion 23 my app compiles ok, but when deployed, that message is displayed in Google Play.
Testing on a Pixel 8 API 35 (Android 15)
